# Stop inside lambda

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
taskQueues.stream().
        filter(aDeque -> !aDeque.isEmpty()).
        map(decks -> decks.stream()). // Breakpoint. Evaluate.
        sorted((a, b) -> {
            return 1;
        });
```

I have marked where breakpoint is put. The image depicts that the stream is not empty. Therefore, I expected that I'll be able to compare something. But I have failed.

[image]

The problem is that I'll be able to understand how to sort only when I stop inside that lambda and have a look at the two objects at hand.

I would like to:

1. Understand the reason why the debugger doesn't stop at line 42.
2. Understand how to make the debugger stop there.

Comment: Keep in mind that streaming from a `Queue` does not remove the elements from said `Queue`. Also, if the actual implementation is, e.g., `PriorityQueue`, which uses a min/max heap, then the encounter order of the elements while streaming is not guaranteed to be the order you'd get by repeatedly polling/removing from the `PriorityQueue`.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 things wrong here:

1. First of all you have to use `flatMap` and not `map` otherwise you are just sorting Collections and not the actual elements of the collection. More info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap)
2. Regarding why the breakpoint is not stopping there, java streams require terminal operations to be evaluated - `sorted` is NOT a terminal operation, so simply adding a terminal operation at the end, such as `toList()` or `.forEach(System.out::println)`, should do the trick.

[More info](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams#pipeline) on terminal operations in java

Corrected version would then be:

```
taskQueues.stream()
        .filter(aDeque -> !aDeque.isEmpty())
        .flatMap(decks -> decks.stream()) // Breakpoint. Evaluate.
        .sorted((a, b) -> {
            return 1;
        })
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```